# Can math be done without syllogisms?

Tags: philosophy-of-mathematics

Question seems self explanatory. Is there anything in mathematics that can be stated to be true without using a logical syllogism?

Had a discussion with somebody about this recently.
Sorry if this is the wrong category.

Comment: Depends on what you mean by "syllogism". One line questions are never self-explanatory, so you should elaborate the post. On standard reading, [syllogisms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syllogism) are figures of argument, so they are not needed to *state* anything.

Comment: Maybe you are referring to something different from [Syllogism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syllogism), which is *monadic (first-order) predicate logic*, i.e. only a fragment of FOL.

Comment: Relevant : J.Corcoran (editor), [Ancient Logic and Its Modern Interpretations (1974)](https://books.google.it/books?id=TBorBgAAQBAJ&pg=PA35) : Ian Mueller's essay and JA Novak, [A Geometrical Syllogism (1978)](https://www.degruyter.com/view/j/apeiron.1978.12.2/apeiron.1978.12.2.26/apeiron.1978.12.2.26.xml)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, since logicians have not seriously used them for the last century or so.  Syllogisms are only included in introductory courses as historical references.  They are not a fundamental aspect of modern logical reasoning.

Comment: You are confusing Aristotle's system with the general idea of a syllogism. The hypothetical and disjunctive syllogisms are used all the time in both formal systems like natural deduction and every day mathematics.

Comment: @Not_Here - but the "weak point" of the question (as per the first comments above) is exactly : what does th OP is meaning with "syllogism" ? Does he conflate it (worngly) with formal logic ?